# How do I apply Styles from my notebook's Style Sheet, in particular Hyphenation->False?

Tags: stylesheet, hyphenation

In my notebook's private style sheet, I set the style for Text to

```
Cell[StyleData["Text"],  Hyphenation->False,  ParagraphIndent->0, 
TabSpacings->{2.9},  FontSize->12]
```

because I encounter too many mal-hyphenated words in German text (btw: is there a spelling check including hyphenation for non-English text?).

I applied Shift-Ctrl-E again to the Text-prototype cell but text cells in the notebook which I had written before did not inherit this property from the changed style sheet, as I fond out when I checked one cell with automatic but wrong hyphenation.

Even a new Text cell which I create after changing of Text Cell's properties in the notebook's style sheet appear as type `Cell["", "Text"]`, i.e. they inherit nothing from my modified prototype.

**What's wrong here?**

**How do I let all styles definitions from the notebook's style sheet apply to all cells with matching type in the notebook?**

Comment: Hyphenation is a little bit hard to test, especially in languages that do not use long words (and it is not a interesting problem). As it seams that you have the same problem with the other parameters, for example `FontSize`, I have played with `FontSize` and it works perfectly. I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: What did you do with FontSize? I also played with FontSize before but it looks like FontSize is not the entity we know from Word or LibreOffice: FontSize->12 looks like 8 point on the screen, good advertizing for eyeglass makers!  Even if in OptionsInspector SelectedNotebook>DisplayOptions>Magnification is 1.0. I even encountered that Magnification on rhe right bottom of my notebook shows 150% and OptionInspector shows 1.25!

Answer (score 2):

In order to switch off Hyphenation e.g. for all Text cells, execute the command

```
SetOptions[#, Hyphenation -> False] & /@ 
  Cells[EvaluationNotebook[], CellStyle -> "Text"];
```

in the notebook. Bingo!

(WRI told me that Hyphenation is a Cell option rather than a Notebook option and together with that answer they gave me this workaround.)